# iPhone SE development support required to get App approved by the Apple review team

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

We are developing an iOS mobile application, We have the plan to give the device support form iPhone 6. But we are not sure that Apple has removed iPhone SE support or not?
So, Please if anyone knows about the same. Please let us know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The iPhone SE is capable of running iOS 12, so even if you target only iOS 12 devices you should support the iPhone SE.  Recently Apple sold "new" iPhone SE devices through their clearance store, so there are iPhone SE devices that are only a couple of months old.  Apple typically reviews on an iPad, so if your app is iPhone only, make sure that it works correctly on an iPad in iPhone resolution.

Comment: [iOS 12 is compatible with these devices](https://www.apple.com/in/ios/ios-12/)

Comment: if your app not supporting iPhone SE dimension it's not a matter. You app is your choice , you can release it. Apple will allow you if your app not supporting iPhone SE device. Because of your app your choice.

Comment: @iOS That isn't really the "Apple" attitude.  Apple users expect apps to be high quality and work on their devices unless there is a genuine reason that an app can't (e.g. requires Apple Pencil support or requires a GPS chip).  While it is true that Apple probably won't reject it, it isn't an attitude I would encourage.

Comment: what do you mean by device support? Are you making screen dimension related stuff? You should target iOS version not the device. If iOS version is supported by SE and something is not good in it then apply might reject the app.

Answer (score 2):

iPhone SE is 9th generation of devices together with iPhone 6s and iPhone 6s Plus. So iPhone SE even newer than iPhone 6.

So as long as Apple supports iPhone 6s it will support SE as well.